# Python: Rotate nested lists -90°

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I'm new to programming and I'm having trouble with a school assignment.
I need to print the heart from 'Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 4', (I already did that.) So now I need to rotate it -90°, I tried multiple solutions, (like reversing the range) but nothing works. What im trying to print is this:

```
....O....
...OOO...
..OOOOO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OO.OO..
```

Here is my code (Spoilers ahead):

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
          ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
          ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
          ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
          ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(6):
    for a in range(9):
        if a < 8:
            print(grid[a][i], end="")
        else:
            print(grid[a][i])
```

I would like to thank y'all in advance.

Comment: Please clarify, reverse or *rotate*?  Given the expected output, it appears you are trying to rotate it -90 degrees.  And ... can you use `numpy`?

Comment: I covered it because I have already done the book lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
          ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
          ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
          ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
          ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(6):
    for a in range(9):
        if a < 8:
            print(grid[a][-(i+1)], end="")
        else:
            print(grid[a][i])

#output
....O....
...OOO...
..OOOOO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OO.OO..
```

Answer (score 1):

For a built-in solution ...

This little bit of code uses list transposition and reverse slicing:

```
list(map(list, zip(*grid)))[::-1]
```

Output:

```
....O....
...OOO...
..OOOOO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OO.OO..
```

Or, if you'd like to use `numpy` ...

Logic:

- Create a `numpy.ndarray` from the `grid`.
- Transpose the array and use reverse slicing to invert the transposed array.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

g = np.array(grid)
g.T[::-1]
```

Which creates an array as:

```
array([['.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
       ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
       ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
       ['.', '.', 'O', 'O', '.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.']], dtype='<U1')
```

And can be printed as:

```
for i in g.T[::-1]:
    print(''.join(i))
```

Output:

```
....O....
...OOO...
..OOOOO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OO.OO..
```

Comments:
I realise the course (most likely) encourages the use of lower-level Python constructs (`list`, `dict`, etc). And I wholly agree this is important / vital.  However, I also feel it's important to expose those new to Python (and development in general) to powerful/efficient libraries such as `numpy`, and how they can be used. Because let's be honest, in the real world ... you're going to write a couple lines in numpy rather than 10 functions to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 0):

A Easy understand way to complete it. (My English is not well, I hope you can understand.)

If it is hard for you to think which one to print,  so to I. I usually create a `reversed_grid` array to save rotated result. The next thing to do is to find the relationship between and `reversed_grid` and `grid` after rotation. I generally look for some specific examples to summarize the general relationship between two arrays. For example, `grid[0][0]` will be stored in `reversed_grid[5][0]` after rotation. There are some other examples. (`[0][5] -> [5][0]` means `grid[0][0]` = `reversed_grid[5][0]`)

```
[0][0] -> [5][0], [0][1] -> [4][0], [0][2] -> [3][0], ... , [0][5] -> [0][0]
[1][0] -> [5][1], [1][1] -> [4][1], [1][2] -> [3][1], ... , [1][5] -> [0][1]
[2][0] -> [5][2], ... 
[3][0] -> [5][3], ... 
... 
[8][0] -> [5][8], ...
```

Through the above examples, you can summarize the relationship is `reversed_grid[6-j][i] = grid[i][j]`. The last thing you have to do is print `reversed_grid` line by line.

The final code is as follows:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
          ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
          ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
          ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
          ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
          ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

reversed_grid = [['' for i in range(9)] for j in range(6)] # create and initialize reversed_grid
for row in range(9):
    for col in range(6):
        reversed_grid[5-col][row] = grid[row][col]

for row in range(6):
    for col in range(9):
        print(reversed_grid[row][col], end='')
    print()
```